# Cannot convert Maven project to App Engine standard project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, google-app-engine, pom.xml

I want to convert a Maven project into an App Engine project for deploying it. But it's giving me the following error as shown in the screenshot below:-

[image: Screenshot]

Following is the screenshot of my Project's properties:-

[image]

Apart from this, when I run my project on localhost, I get the following error:-

> HTTP ERROR 503 Problem accessing /. Reason:
>
> ```
> Service Unavailable
> ```

So, below is the code for my pom.xml, I guess there is something missing from this file:-

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>LiveInBliss</groupId>
  <artifactId>LiveInBliss</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
  <!-- [START resources] -->
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <!-- [END resources] -->

    <plugins>


   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.0.M0</version>
</plugin> 



    <plugin>
   <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
   <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.9.67</version>
    </plugin>




      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>

  <dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
  <version>1.34.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>                        <!-- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/ -->
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-6</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.10</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
<!--
    INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME from Cloud Console > SQL > Instance Details > Properties
    or `gcloud sql instances describe <instance> | grep connectionName`
-->
    <INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>live-in-bliss:northamerica-northeast1:liveinbliss-99</INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>
    <user>root</user>
    <password>my_password</password>
    <database>my_db_name</database>
    <sqlURL>jdbc:mysql://google/$db_name?cloudSqlInstance=$live-in-bliss:northamerica-northeast1:liveinbliss-99&amp;socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&amp;user=$root&amp;password=$my_password&amp;useSSL=false</sqlURL>
  </properties>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with App Engine standard project, but your screenshot looks like you have Dynamic Web Module 2.3 configured.  Per reported issue at [No compatible AppEngine Standard facet found](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/issues/2285), use of the App Engine requires Dynamic Web Module 2.5.

Per the same source, you may also want to check the "jst.web" setting in your org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml file and make sure it agrees with your selected value.

Comment: I changed the Dynamic Web Module to 2.5, but it says "Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 2.5". And, I could not find the org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml file. Thank you

Comment: The file is found in your project under `.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml`.  You can also use the _Open Resource_ (Ctrl-Shift-R) and search for `org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml`.

Can you tell us more about what version of Eclipse you're using?  I'm not sure how your project was bound to the Dynamic Web Facet version 2.3 since your POM is referencing `javax.servlet-api` 3.1.